# Login in external server for Meteor.js

Tags: apache, meteor, authentication, iron-router

Long story short, my Meteor application needs to have login functionalities on an Apache web server (that's because of login APIs of the company who is going to use the app).
Since Meteor apps run on Node.js and not on Apache, the obvious solution seems to be:

1. set up Meteor app with `accounts-password` and `accounts-base`
   packages
2. set up a separate Apache server (probably with some PHP
   backend) for login
3. once logged in, SAFELY pass login username
   from Apache server back to my Meteor app somehow
4. `Meteor.loginWithPassword(username, password)` on Meteor when I have
   username (I will not have the passwords stored on Meteor's db, the only thing I know is that I will have a callback on the Apache server with the username if the user logs in successfully).

What do you think would be a solution to this?

Thanks for your insight

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [nimble:restivus](https://atmospherejs.com/nimble/restivus) or `WebApp` if you are trying to work with more traditional frameworks. With these, you can make a simple ReST Api to return the user id and a token.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  ApiV1 = new Restivus({
    useDefaultAuth: true
  });
}
```

Using this API, you can grab a userId and token

```
$ http post -f user=user@user.org password=password
{
  status: 'success',
  data: {
    token: "somefancytokenhere",
    userId: '123456'
  }
}
```

You can then use `Meteor.loginWithToken` to log in on a meteor service. Eg:

```
Meteor.loginWithToken(myRequest.data.token);
```